# What's the point of have multiple (same resolution) iOS simulators?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I've been developing iOS apps for some time now and I'm aware that the iOS simulators run code faster than their hardware counterparts - i.e. actual devices. I read the following on Apple's *Testing and Debugging in Simulator* documentation site.

> Because the simulator is an app running on a Mac, it has access to the computer’s resources, including the CPU, memory, and network connection. All of these resources are likely to be faster than those found on a mobile device. As a result, the simulator is not an accurate test of an app’s performance, memory usage, and networking speed.

I understand that completely. I also understand that it's important to have multiple simulators to test different size-classes/resolutions.

What I don't understand, however, is why Apple include so many simulators for devices with the same resolution. See the following picture showing iPhone 6, 6s and 7 - all of which have the same screen size and resolution.

[image]

Given that the simulator runs at 'full speed' (regardless of which devices its actually simulating), what's the point of having all those simulators (each taking up a few GB of storage)?

Thanks in advance,

Loic

Comment: Keep in mind that a given device simulator takes up no space if you don't use it.

Comment: Those devices have different hardware configurations. This is reflected in the simulated hardware. The iPhone 6 simulator, for example, won't let you simulate force touch

Comment: Ahhh okay, that makes sense; thanks! If you post that as an answer, I can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each device type attempts to simulate the respective physical device, including features like the presence of force touch. If your trackpad supports force touch the Simulator will translate that into force on the simulated device, but only for device types that support it. There are also things like graphics class and memory class that enable or disable certain behaviors. (In theory Jetsam should more aggressively evict background apps on the iPhone 5 simulator compared to the iPad Pro simulator.)

You can use `xcrun simctl` to create or delete devices, including the default devices though Xcode updates may re-create default devices.

You can also create multiple simulator instances for the same device type if you want different photo libraries, permission settings (grant your app permission to use location in one and deny it in the other), and so forth.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks. Just one question; what is Jetsam?

Comment: When an app is backgrounded it is suspended unless it has an exception (like playing audio), but the system doesn't necessarily unload the process immediately. When a foreground app needs more memory Jetsam finds suspended or low-priority processes and actually unloads them.